‎Office 365 Hybrid Configuration - failed to connect
Externally created mailboxes detected cannot migrate to o365.
It has been discovered that the Office 365 hybrid configuration cannot connect to Outlook.office365.com.
I add photos of errors.
The accounts that are being connected are valid.
The hybrid is installed on the server exchange 2016 cu20
enter image description here
We tried installing updates on the hybrid. Did not help.
Tried to do this
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:5985/wsman/
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:5985/wsman/ sddl=D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-569256582-2953403351-2909559716-1301513147-412116970)(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-4059739203-877974739-1245631912-527174227-2996563517)

It didn't help either.

Problem solved by updating the hybrid
